# How to extend mongoose Query class with Typescript?

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongoose, caching, redis

I'm trying to implement caching with Mongoose, Redis, and Typescript. My `cache.ts` file :

```
import mongoose, { model, Query } from "mongoose";
import redis from "redis";
//import { CacheOptions } from "../../types/mongoose";
type CacheOptions = { key?: string };
const client = redis.createClient();

const getCache = function (
    hashKey: string,
    key: string
): Promise<string | null> {
    return new Promise((res, rej) => {
        client.hget(hashKey, key, (err, val) => {
            if (err) rej(err);
            else res(val);
        });
    });
};

const exec = mongoose.Query.prototype.exec;

mongoose.Query.prototype.cache = function (options: CacheOptions = {}) {
    this.useCache = true;
    this.hashKey = JSON.stringify(options.key || "");

    return this; //make cache() chainable
};

mongoose.Query.prototype.exec = async function () {
    if (!this.useCache) {
        //NO CACHE
        return exec.apply(this);
    }
    const key = JSON.stringify({
        ...this.getQuery(),
        collection: this.model.collection.name,
    });

    const cacheValue = await getCache(this.hashKey, key);

    if (cacheValue) {
        console.log("DATA FROM CACHE");
        const doc = JSON.parse(cacheValue);

        //convert plain object to mongoose object
        return Array.isArray(doc)
            ? doc.map((d) => new this.model(d))
            : new this.model(doc);
    }

    const result = await exec.apply(this);

    client.hset(this.hashKey, key, JSON.stringify(result));
    return result;
};

/**
 *
 * @param hashKey hashkey to remove
 */
const clearHash = (hashKey: string) => {
    client.del(JSON.stringify(hashKey));
};

export { clearHash };
```

And this is my type declaration file under types folder: `mongoose.d.ts`

```
declare module "mongoose" {
    export interface Query<
        ResultType,
        DocType extends Document,
        THelpers = {}
    > {
        cache(): Query<T>;
        useCache: boolean;
        hashKey: string;
        model: Model<T>;
    }
}
```

VsCode IntelliSense doesn't give any warning or error. When I run the code I get following error:

```
    TSError: ⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript:
src/services/product/product.controller.ts:92:67 - error TS2551: Property 'cache' does not exist on type 'Query<IProduct | null, IProduct, {}>'. Did you mean 'catch'?

92  const foundProduct = await Product.findOne({ slug }, { __v: 0 }).cache();
```

I'm not sure if I correctly defined the types but it seems like TypeScript doesn't see my declaration or something else. If you have any suggestion I'll be appreciate.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I solved this issue. In the same cache.ts file do this,

```
declare module 'mongoose' {
    interface DocumentQuery<
        T,
        DocType extends import('mongoose').Document,
        QueryHelpers = {}
    > {
        mongooseCollection: {
            name: any;
        };
        cache(): Promise<DocumentQuery<T[], Document> & QueryHelpers>;
        useCache: boolean;
        hashKey: string;
    }

    interface Query<ResultType, DocType, THelpers = {}, RawDocType = DocType>
        extends DocumentQuery<any, any> {}
}
```

then,

```
mongoose.Query.prototype.cache = function (options: Options = {}) {
    this.__cache = true;
    this.__hashKey = JSON.stringify(options.key || '');

    // To make it chain-able with the queries
    // Ex: Blog
    // .find()
    // .cache()
    // .limit(10)
    return this;
};
```

Because I was not fully confident if the `DocumentQuery<any, any> {}` part is exactly correct so I didn't create it on a separate `mongoose.d.ts` file.
But this code will definitely work.

Answer (score 0):

one alternative option is that you can do is override that Query class in index.d.ts by adding cache: any